# linking functions in shared object - ld

Tags: linux, assembly, linker, nasm, x86-64

I'm trying to write a library (shared object) in assembly. I'm compiling with nasm and linking with ld. I've got 2 ASM files containing differents symbols. I'm trying to call a symbol contained in the first file from the second one, but ld keep throwing an error : `relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol 'strchr' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`.

The first file contains :

```
BITS 64

section .text
    global strchr

strchr:
    push        rbp
    mov         rbp, rsp
    xor         rax, rax
looper:
    cmp         sil, byte [rdi]
    je          saveptr
    cmp         byte [rdi], 0x0
    je          endloop
    inc         rdi
    jmp         looper
saveptr:
    mov         rax, rdi
endloop:
    mov         rsp, rbp
    pop         rbp
    ret
```

The second file contains :

```
BITS 64

section .text
    extern strchr
    global strspn

strspn:
    push        rbp
    mov         rbp, rsp
    xor         rax, rax
    xor         r11, r11
    mov         rax, rdi
looper:
    cmp         byte [rsi], 0x0
    je          endloop
    push        rax
    mov         sil, byte [rsi]
    call        strchr
    cmp         rax, 0x0
    jne         increase
    inc         rsi
    mov         rax, rdi
    jmp         looper
increase:
    inc         r11
    inc         rax
    jmp         looper
endloop:
    mov         rax, r11
    mov         rsp, rbp
    pop         rbp
    ret
```

I'm compiling the library through this process:

```
nasm -f elf64 first_file.asm -o first_file.o
nasm -f elf64 second_file.asm -o second_file.o
ld -shared first_file.o second_file.o -o mylib.so
```

How can I link the first (compiled) ASM file so that I can call the symbol from the second one ?

Comment: You must not use absolute addressing. It requires code change, you can't fix it by linking. Of course you haven't shown your code so can't tell you more. Note that the error message is misleading, it's meant for the case where you are using `gcc` to generate code. It does something else when passed to `ld` so don't do that.

Comment: First of all i'm not using gcc... I'm compilling assembly code, not c... And finally i'm not using absolute addressing otherwise I wouldn't have two files, and i wouldn't be calling export. I would directly call the function through its address.

Comment: You are obviously not using gcc. I am telling you the error message assumes you do, hence the `-fPIC` recommendation which is `gcc` switch, not an `ld` one. Finally, I am pretty sure you do use absolute addressing since that's what the linker is complaining about. Sounds like you don't even know what that is. Hint: it has nothing to do with how many files you have or if any symbols are exported. See also [MCVE].

Comment: Sorry, I misread the error part, I will remove the flag. from this documentation (http://www.osdata.com/topic/language/asm/address.htm) and others absolute addressing is described as the use of the "absolute address" meaning the offset from the beginning of the elf header. As I mentionned, i'm calling the "function" through it's label by explicitly use "call mySymbol" and not "call 0x...".

Comment: The problem is elsewhere. Function calls are relative. And no, it has nothing to do with `0x` (even those would be relative). [MCVE]?

Comment: Thanks for the MCVE. Use `call strchr wrt ..plt` although it isn't immediately obvious why a simple relative call isn't allowed.

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Yes it's weird indeed...